# How to pass a value from one Tableau worksheet to another worksheet's Title

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a sample .twbx that demonstrates what this question is trying to ask but I cannot figure out how to upload it.

I have a Tableau dashboard where I have a dashboard action (menu) where the user can select one of three choices where I want to pass a value (1, 2, or 3) to a second worksheet based on the choice the user made.  The purpose of this ID# of the choice (1,2,3) is to display some text in the Header of my target worksheet.   It's essentially a lookup activity.  I want the choice reflected in the Title of the target worksheet.

I can't figure out how to pass the selection ID to this second worksheet.  I have attached some screenshots that I hope will paint the picture of what I'm after.

Here are the Menu choices.
[image]

Here is a sample of what I'm after with the proper text in the Title of the target page.
[image]

Here is the calculation fields and the calculation field that should select the text.
[image]
[image]

Here is the vertical with one horizonal (Toggled Lookups).  I can't wedge in another horizontal.
[image]

[image]

An example using the Sample-Superstore database.

Comment: I don't think you can't pass from worksheet to worksheet.  Only worksheet to dashboard. At least, in all of the Tableau courses I've taken, it's always been worksheet to dashboard.  Look at [Filter Actions](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/actions_filter.htm)

Comment: The worksheet -to- dashboard might be the answer.

Comment: You can pass worksheet to worksheet via calculated fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a dashboard; create a new worksheet, this will function as your title and will only return a single value of your created calculated field (let's call it `[get_ID]`) to the *Text* pane.

Create a new calculated field where the distinct count of `[get_ID]` must be 1 so you only ever return the single ID. Something like:

```
IF COUNTD([get_ID]) = 1 THEN [get_ID] END
```

Call it `[get_ID FILTER]` and drag this to your filter pane on the worksheet and set it to ***True***. Now you have a sheet that will only return a single ID based on your selections.

Add this sheet to your dashboard and format it so it looks like a title. Easiest way to do it is to put this and the target sheet into a vertical container.

Since you will not always have a single ID selected, I would put a horizontal container at the top of the vertical. In it I would add two things:

- A text box

  - Insert your parameter to this text object and it will always show the one you have selected (even if you have more than one ID currently selected)
- The new sheet we just created

This way the new sheet is blank until you have single ID selected where it would populate as a dynamic title.

Comment: I have a sample .twbx but I can't see where to attach it.  The example dashboard works as I want, but now you can see where I need the dynamic text to display.  Hope this helps.   I'm increasingly confident this can be done.   Just need a little more help.